# express.js form-module for mongoose

Tags: forms, node.js, express, mongoose

I am searching for a node.js compatible form handler, mapper, validator, renderer which uses mongoose models to create a form.

Does somebody can recommand me a package?

I found these two:

1. https://github.com/oJshua/mongoose-forms
2. https://github.com/GothAck/forms-mongoose

but they haven't been updated for a while....

Comment: I now went a bit deeper into express.js. Wouldn't it be better to let the form get rendered client side (with Backbone.Form for example) but how could I share schemas or should I maintain the schemas independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I checked out different form modules.

First I used the "forms" module. Than I checked out the src code of https://github.com/GothAck/forms-mongoose and found out that it depends on "forms" only extended by reading the mongoose models. So you dan't have to write an extra schema for the forms.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to checkout Formage (npm:formage)

https://github.com/Empeeric/formage